# BufferedImage to byte: how are the channels mapped?

Tags: java, byte, bufferedimage, rgba

I am converting a `BufferedImage` to `byte[]` array using the following code:

```
BufferedImage input = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
DataBufferByte bufferBytes = (DataBufferByte) input.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
byte[] bytes = bufferBytes.getData();
```

One thing that is getting me confused is that how are the channels mapped to actual byte elements? Assuming that I have an ARGB image for the first pixel in the image, starting from `bytes[0]` and working through `bytes[3]`, which element is the red channel, which one is the green channel, which one is the blue channel and which one is the alpha channel?

I did some test runs and checked each element in the debugging mode, but my results were inconclusive (am I missing something?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [BufferedImage.getType()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getType%28%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment on my original question, I found the answer.
Looking at the result of `BufferedImage.getType()` along with JavaDoc, will help you determine the mapping of the colors in the `byte[]` array.

In my case, the type of the image was `TYPE_3BYTE_BGR` which according to Java documentation, is stored as interleaved Blue, Green, Red in 3 consecutive byte elements.

Hope this helps others :-)